Mocking Java CompletableFuture.supplyAsync
I have the following sample code. Calling different static methods from utility classes in different Completable Futures and joining them to get results together.
However, while writing JUnits, call is going inside the utility class even if I am doing the static mock. If i remove the Completable Future implementation, JUnits are working fine with mock.
Is there anything I am missing or need to mock Completable Future in different way?
My Code :
CompletableFuture Code:
package com.demo.futures;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class CompletableFutureSample {

    public List<String> myShortTaskWithoutCompletableFuture() {

        System.out.println("Inside myShortTaskWithoutCompletableFuture");

        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();

        res.add(MyUtils1.getSampleValue1("Ranesh"));

        return res;
    }

    public List<String> myShortTask() {

        System.out.println("Inside myShortTask");

        List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();

        CompletableFuture<String> future1 = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(() -> MyUtils1.getSampleValue1("Ranesh"));

        futures.add(future1);

        try {
            CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
            for (CompletableFuture<String> future : futures) {
                res.add(future.get());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return res;
    }

    public List<String> myTask() {

        List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();

        CompletableFuture<String> future1 = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(() -> MyUtils1.getSampleValue1("Ranesh"));

        CompletableFuture<String> future2 = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(() -> MyUtils2.getSampleValue2("Ranesh"));

        CompletableFuture<String> future3 = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(() -> MyUtils3.getSampleValue3("Ranesh"));

        futures.add(future1);
        futures.add(future2);
        futures.add(future3);

        try {
            CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
            for (CompletableFuture<String> future : futures) {
                res.add(future.get());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return res;
    }

}


Utility Class:
package com.demo.futures;

public class MyUtils1 {

    public static String getSampleValue1(String str) {
        System.out.println("Inside My Utils 1");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return "Hello : " + str;
    }

}


My JUnit class :
package com.demo.futures;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.MockedStatic;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CompletableFutureSampleTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private CompletableFutureSample completableFutureSample;

    private MockedStatic<MyUtils1> myUtils1MockedStatic;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        completableFutureSample = new CompletableFutureSample();
        myUtils1MockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(MyUtils1.class);
    }

    @Test
    void testMyShortTaskWithoutCompletableFuture() {

        myUtils1MockedStatic.when(() -> MyUtils1.getSampleValue1(anyString())).thenReturn("Test String Result");
        List<String> res = completableFutureSample.myShortTaskWithoutCompletableFuture();
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, res.size());
        Assertions.assertEquals("Test String Result", res.get(0));

    }

    @Test
    void testMyShortTask() {

        myUtils1MockedStatic.when(() -> MyUtils1.getSampleValue1(anyString())).thenReturn("Test String Result");
        List<String> res = completableFutureSample.myShortTask();
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, res.size());
        Assertions.assertEquals("Test String Result", res.get(0));

    }

    @Test
    void testMyTask() {

    }

    @AfterEach
    void cleanUp() {
        myUtils1MockedStatic.close();
    }

}


While executing test : testMyShortTask, call is going inside utility method.

There's been an open issue for years about this ISSUE-2142.
Essentially stubbing static resources won't be available outside the main thread.
Stubbing static / private resources is always gonna have some limitations. If you can, try to inject your dependencies. CompletableFuture runs by default on the ForkJoin-pool and may lead to thread starvation depending on your context. Good practice would be to inject an ExecutorService which you control better and could mock more easily if absolutely required.
public String myShortTask() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    return executorService.submit(() -> MyUtils1.getSampleValue1("Ranesh")).get();
}

@Test
void testMyShortTask() {

    when(executorService.submit((Callable<String>) any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
        final Callable<?> callable = invocation.getArgument(0);
        var value = callable.call();
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(value);
    });

    myUtils1MockedStatic.when(() -> MyUtils1.getSampleValue1(anyString())).thenReturn("Test String Result");

    String res = completableFutureSample.myShortTask();

    Assertions.assertEquals("Test String Result");
}

